# How does SVG decimal color values (0 to 1) translate to (0 to 255) color values?

Tags: svg

The following code clearly demonstrates, that decimal color values (0,1), doesn't translate linearly to descrete values (0,255). If they were, 0,5 would translate to about 128, but it doesn't. Instead, it translates to around 187.

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="coltrans">
      <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic">
        <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
        <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <lineargradient id="0to1gradient">
    <stop offest="0" stop-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(255,0,0)"/>
  </lineargradient>
  <rect filter="url(#coltrans)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="url(#0to1gradient)" stroke="blue"/>
  <rect x="0" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="url(#0to1gradient)" stroke="blue"/>
</svg>
```

In the lower rectangle color is linearly progressed from white to red.
The upper rectangle has the same color transition, only it is filtered, so that green and blue decimal color values are rounded up or down to the closest point (0 or 1).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation-filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most colour operations in SVG are done in the **sRGB** colour space.  But, for visual quality reasons, filter operations are (by default) performed in the **linearRGB** colour space. Any input images are converted to lineaRGB, the filter primitives are applied, and then the output of the filter is converted back to sRGB.

For more details, read the [sRGB Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) or the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#filters-FilterPrimitivesOverview).

But what it basically boils down to is that sRGB is a gamma adjusted version of RGB.  This was originally in order to compensate for the response of old CRT monitors. In order to display a pixel at about half brightness, you had to send 187 to the screen instead of 128.

The overall gamma factor works out to *approximately* 2.2.

So to (roughly) convert from linearRGB to sRGB, raise the input value to the power of (1 / 2.2)

```
0.5 ^ (1/2.2) = 0.7297

0.7297 * 256 ~= 187
```